# send a vue component PROPS from .ejs file

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ejs, nuxt.js

I am trying to send a prop to vue component from .ejs file.

every time I do so it sent as undefined value.

I created people-view component and here is my code in calling it.

```
<people-view componentName="Something" :componentValue="obj.value"/>
```

Note that **componentName** is static string and **componentValue** is dynamic value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the vue component that uses this template?

Comment: Please post your `app.js` route for the template you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem was that ejs can't parse camel case component name,
the solution is to change "componentName" to "componentname"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing `obj` as context to the view, then you need to wrap the variable in `<%= %>` tags:

```
<people-view componentName="Something" :componentValue="<%= obj.value %>"/>
```

Comment: Thank you , the problem was that ejs can't parse camel case component name,
the solution is to change "componentName" to "componentname"

Comment: @AhmedSaidBakheet You should answer your own question so others don't make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that ejs can't parse camel case component name, the solution is to change "componentName" to "componentname"

```
<people-view componentname="Something" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`<people-view 
      v-bind:data_one="<%= string_data %>"
      v-bind:data_two="<%= JSON.stringify(JSON_data) %>">
</people-view>`

You can use the first binding if you send `string_data` as a stringified JS Object or you can use the second one to just stringify it as you receive it from the backend route.

The reason is v-bind needs a string value to pass to the component. I used this in a recent project.